# Problem on applying script when i send the email

Tags: outlook

Does anyone know how to trigger VBA when i sent out an email.

I tried to look for the option from Rule Wizard on "Apply rule on message i send" but there is script option.

Cheers

Comment: Please share some code or your trials, on base of that things we can able to share proper way to look out your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you may assign a VBA sub to run when your rule is triggered. The sub should take a single argument which represents the item being sent:

```
Public Sub Test(item as Outlook.MailItem)
  ' run your code here
End Sub
```

You may add an event handler to the [ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event of the `Application` class. It is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program.

```
Public WithEvents myOlApp As Outlook.Application 

Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
  Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application  
End Sub 

Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
 Dim prompt As String  
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?"  
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then  
  Cancel = True  
 End If  
End Sub
```

You write an event procedure (also known as an event handler) to respond to events that occur in Microsoft Outlook. For example, you can write an event procedure that automatically maximizes the explorer window when Outlook starts.

Events are associated with particular objects. The `Application` object is the topmost object, and is always available (that is, it does not have to be created). You can add an `Application` event procedure in the `ThisOutlookSession` module window simply by selecting `Application` in the left list and then selecting the event in the right list.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation! I will try all of these.